# Leaves of a tree made up of internal nodes with either 3 or 2 children

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I'm currently struggling with solving the following problem: given a tree *T* made up of *n* internal nodes, where *n-k* nodes have 2 children and *k* nodes have 3 children, demonstrate that T has *n+k+1* leaves.

Can anyone help me or point me to the right direction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Count the total number of edges in the tree. Then remember that in a tree graph there is a simple relation between the total number of edges and the total number of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a while I managed to solve this.

Being *m* the number of leaves, and *n* the number of internal nodes, we know that the size of the tree equals the total number of nodes, which is then *m+n*.

Now we know that the sum of the degrees of all nodes *tot_deg = size-1*, so *tot_deg = m+n-1*. We can write *tot_deg* as *2(n-k) + 3k* (number of children per each node multiplied by number of nodes).

We then solve the equation *2(n-k) + 3k = m+n-1* obtaining *m*, demonstrating that it's equal to *n+k+1*.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of the tree as a family tree, and what a node with 2 children does to the number of nodes in the next generation... What does a node with 3 children do? Hope this helps